# How do I optionally specify a function argument in Python?

Tags: python

In this example, I have a function with an optional argument. E.g.

```
def func_x(arg_foo='foo'):
  # Do something
  pass
```

While calling the function, I'd like to specify arguments only under certain conditions.

This is one way of doing it.

```
if cond == True:
  func_x(arg_foo='coo')
else:
  func_x()
```

However, the real-life example I have (which is actually a boto3 dynamodb query function) has **many** optional arguments which I'd like to specify under certain conditions.

I'd prefer not to do the following if I have the choice:

```
if condition_a:
  long_func_call(many_optional_argument_names=many_optional_argument_values)
elif condition_b:
  long_func_call(many_optional_argument_names=many_optional_argument_values)
elif condition_c:
  long_func_call(many_optional_argument_names=many_optional_argument_values)
else:
  long_func_call(many_optional_argument_names=many_optional_argument_values)
```

I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
long_func_call(
  arg1='' if cond_a else 'value',
  arg2=None if cond_b else 'value'
)
```

The function I'm calling doesn't accept '' nor None as inputs to its optional arguments.

Is there a way I can specify optional arguments given certain conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
kwargs = {}
if condition_a:
    kwargs['arg_a'] = value_a
if condition_b:
    kwargs['arg_b'] = value_b
...
long_func_call(**kwargs)
```

Use a dict of keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lambda

```
if cond:
  func = lambda:func_x(arg_foo='coo')
else:
  func = func_x
func()
```